# How we add Owin with Azure classical worker role

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-worker-roles

I am new .net framework, Basically i want to create Azure worker role with Own startup class. But I don't know how to do it.

I follow this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/host-owin-in-an-azure-worker-role) but not work for me it throw an exception that i asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62096740/null-references-exception-in-net-core-owin)